# UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

I'm new to `UICollectionView` and I'm following a tutorial I found on the web but I'm stuck on an error I can't figure out. Here's a bit of context.

In the debugger I can see that following is happening:

- `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView`: is called and I return 1
- `collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:` is called and I return the size of the model (20)
- `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` gets called once for each item in the model
- `collectionView:layout:insetForSectionAtIndex:` is called
- `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` gets called and it crashes on this line...

  ```
  UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
  ```

with this error...

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'
```

When I pause execution on that line and check the console it appears that there is a layout...

```
(lldb) po collectionView.collectionViewLayout
(UICollectionViewLayout *) $4 = 0x07180fd0 <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7180fd0>
```

The `UICollectionView` is part of the one and only scene in the storyboard. In viewController.m there are no other `UICollectionView`s created by any means.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: That error comes when you make a new collection view using alloc/init or new, rather than adding a layout object when you initialise. Are you making a new collection view anywhere?

Comment: @jrturton Not that I know of. The UICollectionView is part of the one and only scene in the storyboard. In viewController.m there are no UICollectionViews created by any means. But with that said, and being new to collection views, I'm not sure where the layout gets associated with the collection view.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As it turns out the problem was with `registerClass:`. I had this:

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionView class] 
        forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
```

but it should have been this:

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] 
        forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
```

So the dequeue method was creating a `UICollectionView` instead of a `UICollectionViewCell`.

Answer (score 32):

This worked for me :

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *aFlowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [aFlowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(200, 140)];
    [aFlowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
myCollectionViewController = [[MyCollectionViewController alloc]initWithCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
```

If you are creating UICollectionView programmatically a layout is required.

Comment: sorry, that's not it. As I mentioned in the question this is coming out of a storyboard and as shown in the console output there is a valid layout for the collection view. See my answer for what the problem turned out to be.

Comment: Yes that is also essential. You had a wrong class assigned to the cell.

Answer (score 8):

If you are making collection view controller programmatically in UICollectionViewController make sure that **UICollectionViewController init** method uses [super initWithCollectionViewLayout] instead of [super init], e.g.:

```
-(id) initWithImages:(NSArray *)pImages {
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [layout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:0.0f];
    [layout setMinimumLineSpacing:0.0f];
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
    if (self = [super initWithCollectionViewLayout:layout]) {
        _images= [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:pImages];
    }
    return self;
}
```

From: [UICollectionViewController Class Reference:Overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewController_clas/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 3):

i got the same problem and mine got solved by using

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *myLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];
[myLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
[myLayout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:0.0f];
[myLayout setMinimumLineSpacing:0.0f];
UICollectionView *myCollectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:viewfame collectionViewLayout:myLayout];
```

instead of

```
UICollectionView *myCollectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[myLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
[myLayout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:0.0f];
[myLayout setMinimumLineSpacing:0.0f];
[myCollectionView setCollectionViewLayout:myLayout];
```

Answer (score 1):

If your class is Inherit from UICollectionViewController or you are creating UICollectionView programmatically then while pushing the class you can set collectionViewLayout like below

```
let homeViewController = HomeViewContoller(collectionViewLayout:UICollectionViewLayout())
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this issue when returning a UICollectionViewLayout object with itemSize equal to self.view.bounds before the view had been initialized.